# How do I Combine these SQL SELECT queries into one SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, syntax, select, union

How do I combine these two select statements into one query:

```
SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS fires, neighborhoods AS fire_neighborhoods
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo
GROUP BY fire_neighborhoods ORDER BY fires DESC



SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS adw, neighborhoods AS adw_neighborhoods
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo2
GROUP BY adw_neighborhoods ORDER BY adw DESC
```

So, I'd like the query to return, something like:

```
fire_neighborhoods  fires  adw_neighborhoods  adw
xyzNeighborhood     6      abcNeighborhood    22
jklNeighborhood     3      tuvNeighborhood    40
```

I want to simply combine the results of the two queries above. The two queries are independent of each other. The results of one doesn't effect the results of the other query. I simply need a way to slam the two results together into one.

If anyone has any advice, please let me know.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I must be missing something. Why can't you just UNION the two queries together?

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables?

Comment: And why are people voting this question up? Is this question really useful? It seems rather academic and superfluous to me.

Comment: @Jim G.: Blame the Electorate badge: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate

Comment: Why is the schema mapped one table per year? Are those views?

Comment: Hi Jim,
In effect, they are views. To make a long story short, there is code that determines whether an incident is inside a neighborhood. It runs too slowly. So, I've run it in advance of the user requesting it and thrown it into these tables. It's not great, but it works. 

I'm still learning.  

Thanks.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the the help in figuring this out. Shout out to David Hall, Aaron, Jeffrey Whitledge & NYSystemsAnalyst. I went with the dummy column option:

```
SELECT SUM( incidents ) , neighborhoods,  'adw' as offense 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo 
GROUP BY neighborhoods  
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM( incidents ), neighborhoods,  'fire' as offense 
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `fire_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fire_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fire_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fire_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo2
GROUP BY neighborhoods
```

Answer (score 3):

The example you gave indicates you want to combine the queries horizontally, but then you later stated they are completely independent.  These are conflicting statements because you normally combine data horizontally when records do relate to one another.  Below is my idea for combining them horizontally, but I also make note of my idea for combining them vertically below that.

It depends how you want to link them up.  If you are querying based on neighborhood, you can do a join between the two larger queries on fire_neighborhoods = adw_neighborhoods, such as:

```
SELECT fire_neighborhoods, fires, adw
FROM (

SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS fires, neighborhoods AS fire_neighborhoods
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo
GROUP BY fire_neighborhoods ORDER BY fires DESC

) AS fires
    INNER JOIN (  

SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS adw, neighborhoods AS adw_neighborhoods
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo2
GROUP BY adw_neighborhoods ORDER BY adw DESC

) AS adw
    ON fires.fire_neighborhoods = adw.adw_neighborhoods
```

This is just an example.  You may need a different join or something to make it work for you.

Now, you stated that the two queries are independent and do not affect one another.  If they really do have no common ground, you should add a column to each query indicating the query it came from (e.g. add a column with a constant value of 1 for the fire query and a column with a constant value of 2 for the adw query).  Then, just UNION the two large queries together.  This would combine them in a vertical fashion as opposed to a horizontal fashion.

Comment: Hi NYSystemsAnalyst,

Thank you for the suggestion of adding columns with constants. I'll probably end up doing that.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you need correctly, you can UNION the queries together, adding a column to let you know which query it came from:

```
SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS fires_or_adw, neighborhoods AS fire_or_adw_neighborhoods, 'Fires' as which_query
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `fires_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo
GROUP BY fire_neighborhoods ORDER BY fires DESC

UNION

SELECT SUM( incidents )  AS fires_or_adw, neighborhoods AS fire_or_adw_neighborhoods, 'ADW' as which_query
FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2009_incident_location` 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2008_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2007_incident_location`
UNION ALL SELECT * 
FROM `adw_2006_incident_location`
) AS combo2
GROUP BY adw_neighborhoods ORDER BY adw DESC
```

Granted you'll have twice as many rows and half your data will be null, but just "slamming" the results together as in your example isn't usual.

Comment: Hi Aaron,

I guess that I don't need to return the data horizontally.

I could add a column that will indicate whether it is fire or adw and then have the other columns be neighborhood and incidents.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Hi Aaron,
I forgot to say "thank you" in my previous message. 

Sorry.
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1):

The answers given by the others of using a discriminator column look like what you are after, but just in case, it is possible to add dummy place holder columns to unions as shown below:

```
SELECT 
    SUM( incidents )  AS fires, 
    neighborhoods AS fire_neighborhoods,
    0 as adw,
    '' as adw_neighbourhoods
FROM ( 
    SELECT *  
    FROM `fires_2009_incident_location`  
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `fires_2008_incident_location` 
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `fires_2007_incident_location` 
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `fires_2006_incident_location` 
) AS combo 
GROUP BY fire_neighborhoods ORDER BY fires DESC 

UNION 

SELECT 
    0 as fires,
   '' as fire_neighbourhoods,
    SUM( incidents )  AS adw, 
    neighborhoods AS adw_neighborhoods 
FROM ( 
    SELECT *  
    FROM `adw_2009_incident_location`  
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `adw_2008_incident_location` 
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `adw_2007_incident_location` 
    UNION ALL SELECT *  
    FROM `adw_2006_incident_location` 
) AS combo2 
GROUP BY adw_neighborhoods ORDER BY adw DESC
```

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the message. I tried your suggestion and unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work. Is it possible to add dummy columns in mySQL? 

-Laxmidi

Comment: @Laxmidi - are you seeing an error when you run that syntax? I'm not sure about mySQL, though I expect it should work. Tour question was retagged by someone as being tsql which is the microsoft sql implementation, I'm going to retag it now.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying two unrelated queries side-by-side is usually the job of the reporting software rather than the SQL engine. The problem here is that you are asking the query tool to do something that it is not suited to do: display formatting.

A relation (which is what the result of a SELECT is supposed to be, fundamentally) is a data structure that makes assertions about the state of the world. Each row defines a series of propositions which are (ideally) true.

In your question, the rows contain arbitrary concatinations of facts which do not relate to one another and about which no propositions can be stated.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,

You're right. It doesn't make sense to return the data horizontally.

Thanks

-Laxmidi