# How to combine these two Queries in single one.?

Tags: mysql

these are my two queries When i fired them separately i gives correct response but when combined they do not give the same response. Please help to combine them

```
SELECT SUM(hours) AS S1
,operating_company
 FROM Hours WHERE operating_company='AP-OH' GROUP BY operating_company

SELECT COUNT(*) AS S1,event_type
,operating_company
 FROM Event WHERE operating_company='AP-OH' AND event_type='OSH Restricted' GROUP BY 
 operating_company,event_type
```

Thanks 
RajeshB

Comment: With different grouping, the result of course will be different. Which result do you want?

Comment: are you trying to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374778/how-do-i-combine-these-sql-select-queries-into-one-select-statement)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  e.event_type,
  e.operating_company,
  SUM(h.hours) AS S1,
  COUNT(e.*) AS S2
FROM Hours h 
INNER JOIN event e ON h.operating_company = e.operating_company
WHERE h.operating_company = 'AP-OH' 
  AND e.event_type        = 'OSH Restricted' 
GROUP BY e.operating_company, e.event_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT SUM(S1.hours) ,S1.operating_company ,S2.operating_company ,COUNT(S2.*),S2.event_type , S2.operating_company
   FROM Hours as S1 WHERE operating_company='AP-OH' 

   INNER JOIN event AS S2 
   ON    S2.operating_company = S1.operating_company
    WHERE S2.operating_company=S1.operating_company='AP-OH' AND S2.event_type='OSH Restricted'
   GROUP BY 
   S2.operating_company,S2.event_type
```